# Imported target "Eigen3::Eigen" includes non-existent path

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to run cmake but I got this error

```
CMake Error in src/CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "Eigen3::Eigen" includes non-existent path

    "/usr/include/eigen3"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.
```

This message appears twice and then it says "Generating done" (so it finished?)

My CMakeLists.txt file uses the `find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)` as in

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myapplication PRIVATE "-rdynamic" Threads::Threads nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json spdlog::spdlog ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${GST_LIBRARIES} snpe Eigen3::Eigen ${lib_list})
target_include_directories(myapplication
  PUBLIC ${inc_dirs_list}
  INTERFACE ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
  PUBLIC ${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )
```

What could be happening and how to solve it?

EDIT:
I have edited the Cmake file with

```
message(STATUS, "Eigen_Path = ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

and the path it gives (that is later used in target_include_directories) exists! the last part of that path is indeed */usr/include/eigen3* so I don't know why the message error appears

for reference the contents of that path is

```
Eigen  
signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library  
unsupported
```

Comment: It seems you actually don't have Eigen **installed**. We could only guess about origin of `ConfigEigen3.cmake` file which is found by CMake when it resolved `find_package(Eigen3)` call. Smells like you have **built** Eigen and found that file in the build directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I ve edited the question with more information.